# use fromhtml is bigger than textview

Tags: android

when use Html.fromHtml in textview 
it displayed more width than textview width and some characters disappear

what can i do ?

like this image

[image]

html code

```
hello <font color=red>world</font>
```

when i change font tag to span it works fine but characters not colored

no duplicated
 i use html not spannable and your link is describe span not html

Comment: Pl share the html code you are using.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: hello <font color=red>world</font>